# Swipeable table view cell with default action

Tags: ios, ios8, swipe, uitableview

iOS8 now provides a way to create swipeable table view cell with actions.  In Apple's own Mail app, you can also commit to a default action if you drag the cell all the way (Mail app shows More | Flag | Trash and defaults to Trash if you drag all the way and release).  Is there a way to do this in iOS 8?

Comment: Which of Apple's apps are you referring to? So we can get a reference of exactly what you mean.

Comment: Are you talking about how the mail app swipes all the way?

Comment: @BenKane Mail app - where it shows More | Flag | Trash, and if you drag all the way and release, it does the Trash action.

Comment: @theMonster Yes mail app.

Comment: @Boon Unfortunately, this functionality is custom and isn't built in.

Answer (score 0):

If your are referring to the swipe to delete on TableViews you can use this code:

```
//Enable multiple selections during editing
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;

//Enable editing row
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

//Do something on delete
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //add code here for when you hit delete
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not in a public API yet. Luckily, someone has already done the legwork :)

[JASwipeCell](https://github.com/joseria/JASwipeCell)